# Error when using UNPIVOT in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, unpivot, stdev

I have the following query:

```
    SELECT STDEV(Value) as Value, TimeOfTest as Date
    FROM myTable
    unpivot
    (
        value
        for col in (WS1, WS2, WS3, WS4, WS5, WS6, WS7, WS8, WS9, WS10, WS11, 
                    WS12, WS13, WS14, WS15, WS16, WS17, WS18, WS19, WS20)
    ) un
    GROUP BY TimeOfTest
    ORDER BY TimeOfTest DESC
```

but I get an SQL server 2008 error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FOR'

Would anyone know the reason why? The syntax looks correct.

Comment: Shouldn't the WS1 be enclosed in ''s? 'WS1' etc

Comment: for unpivot no need to add single quotes as we will mention the column names in the 'in' clause available at unpivot clause

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `APPLY`.

```
SELECT t.TimeOfTest, STDEV(ws) as Value
FROM myTable t CROSS APPLY(
     (VALUES (WS1), (WS2), . . . (WS20)) v(ws)
GROUP BY t.TimeOfTest
ORDER BY t.TimeOfTest DESC;
```

`APPLY` implements something called a "lateral join".  This is a very powerful (and ANSI-standard) construct, that can be used for many things beyond unpivoting.  On the other hand, `unpivot` is very specific syntax that is used for only one purpose . . . and as you have found, may not work well other constructs such as `GROUP BY` (I think you could resolve your issue by using a subquery).

Comment: don't ws1 etc. need quotes?

Comment: This worked great for me! @GeorgeMenoutis the values do not need to be in quotes.

Comment: well, nice! unpivoting with cross apply is so much easier, more intuitional, and configurable than the unpivot operator.